# Protect specific sheets on workbook open

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to protect all sheets in my workbook apart from one where i have a macro button.

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Rota"
        Case Else: ws.Protect password:="1234", userinterfaceonly:=True
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

The problem is that the macro creates new sheets which i don't want to be protected when the workbook is opened. I only need to protect sheets 1 to 6. Can anyone help me modify the code please?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For i = 1 To 6
        Sheets("Sheet" & i).Protect Password:="1234", userinterfaceonly:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

and if the sheets are not named "Sheet1", "Sheet2", ..., just loop over the sheet names.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 6
    Sheets(i).Protect password:="1234", userinterfaceonly:=True
Next i
End Sub
```

I think the problem with the solution above was that i hadn't been set as a variable.